# Unable to send push notification after 1 minute

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, scheduler, jobs

I am facing one weird issue in Laravel Job/Scheduler. In my backend, I have created one functionality using which the admin can schedule push notification and send it to all users. So let say I have created one notification that sends a notification to all users at 2:00 AM. So at 2:00 AM one entry added to the Jobs table and start sending a push notification. but it will send push notifications for only 1 minute. After 1 minute it is stopping the push notification send process. I have more than 1k users on the notification list. But it is sending push notifications to only 50 user approx. I have used a scheduler for handling jobs.

Please help me. I have tried all possible ways from my end to identify the issue.

Comment: How long are your queue workers set to run? If it's default it could be timing out after 1 minute.

Comment: Schuler is running after every 1 minute. I have increased my push notification time to 1 minute to 5 minutes. But the result is the same.

Comment: Yes, but the job is pushed onto a queue correct? Are you running a worker on the queue?

Comment: Yes. Job Pushed onto queue (Jobs) table. And the supervisor is running that job.